# How does my requests stopped working in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-requests

I had this this python3 script running normally using requests.get. However if I switched to another directory other than the one I am working at this error pops up. I tried reinstall requests using pip3 and rename the file but neither worked for me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bs.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    import threading
  File "/Users/pavel/Documents/Code/threading.py", line 10, in <module>
    url = requests.get(host,headers = headers)
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: you named your python script to threading.py rename that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File "/Users/pavel/Documents/Code/threading.py", line 10, in <module>
    url = requests.get(host,headers = headers)
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'
```

Here,"/Users/pavel/Documents/Code/" is your working directory?

When importing something python searches the working directory first so, `import threading` from anywhere would try to import your threading.py which will make circular reference to `requests`. Right now requests module is also importing other modules so method `get` isn't yet defined. That's why the error.

Try renaming your script somthing else. You have to always be careful of the names like that, if you are going to use a module don't name your python script with the same name. Also be careful of other basic python modules.

Comment: Oh well I should have realized that but only focusing on searching for requests.py . Thanks for the explanation!